# It it possible to detect the source of traffic using Rails/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, analytics, web-traffic

I want to detect whether a user came to my site directly or via a link, and if they used a link then I want to detect what url they came from.

This must be possible somehow, because analytics software can do it. It it achievable with Rails or jQuery?

Comment: Use `document.referrer`

Comment: this is very usefull and handy gem for tracking such analytics on server side. https://github.com/ankane/ahoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes and no.**

Some clients send a header called `referer` (Yes its a misspelling). You can access the header through `document.referer` in javascript or `request.referer` in Rails.

However you cannot rely on the presence of the header as many clients do not send it. For a very good reason as it can be used to track users - often without their knowledge or consent.

The `referer` header can also be spoofed so using it in any kind of authentication scheme is not a good idea.

Another approach is by attaching a query parameter to links with a tracking code. This requires you to be in control of the incoming links.